# Why axios sending get request three times to server

Tags: reactjs, axios

Instead of sending one request to get data from server why it is sending three times to get one data from  server.

```
import React from 'react';               
import axios from "axios";
export const Components = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/posts')
      .then(res => setData(res.data))
  },[])
  return data.map((p, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>{p.title}</p>
  })
}

export default Components;
```

Here you can see what output I am getting when calling an API.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you followed the advice provided in the answer below just so you know, it's normal that you see two logs in console with the data even after you add the empty dependency array to `useEffect`. This is because of React's `StrictMode`.

Comment: I am getting more than three in network tab.Little confuse what's happening.

Comment: It is also applicable to other as well when fetching from json placeholders

Comment: That's weird... You shouldn't be seeing more than 2 requests. I can't see anything in the code you provided that could result in that extra request.

Comment: @ivanatias You can see now that it each value fetched  = three times.

Comment: From your image, if you are getting _three **rendered** values_, then that's because your endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/posts` is returning an array with three elements. Isn't it?

Comment: Nope! it just for this one component others are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not providing a dependencies array (second argument) to `useEffect`. When you don't provide such argument, the effect is executed on every render.

Assuming you want the effect to run only once, fix it by adding an empty array:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/posts')
      .then(res => setData(res.data))
  }, []); // <------- changed here
```

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), **you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument**. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

**Caveat:** this will still run twice ***during development*** if you are using [React Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

There are new docs on the best practices for [fetching data in React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data) if you want to learn more about the subject.

Comment: Nothing change same output @acdcjunior

Comment: That's correct, the output shouldn't change. The difference is that this code now will only make one axios call, not many.

Comment: I mean still now I am getting one data three times instead of getting data one time.@acdcjunior

Comment: I updated the answer, but the code really is supposed to be just `}, []);`. The caveat is that if you are using React's strict mode, during development the `useEffect` will run **twice**. But never three times. Are you positive you are seeing three calls? If so, we have a different issue.